# SendGrid Inbound Parse Webhook in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, sendgrid

I'm trying to implement the code snippet for inbound parse from the [SendGrid docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/tracking-events/csharp-code-example/) which parses an inbound Sendgrid email, but it does not seem to work on .net-core.

```
// POST api/inbound
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
{
    var root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

    var email = new Email
    {
        Dkim = provider.FormData.GetValues("dkim").FirstOrDefault(),
        To = provider.FormData.GetValues("to").FirstOrDefault(),
        Html = provider.FormData.GetValues("html").FirstOrDefault(),
        From = provider.FormData.GetValues("from").FirstOrDefault(),
        Text = provider.FormData.GetValues("text").FirstOrDefault(),
        SenderIp = provider.FormData.GetValues("sender_ip").FirstOrDefault(),
        Envelope = provider.FormData.GetValues("envelope").FirstOrDefault(),
        Attachments = int.Parse(provider.FormData.GetValues("attachments").FirstOrDefault()),
        Subject = provider.FormData.GetValues("subject").FirstOrDefault(),
        Charsets = provider.FormData.GetValues("charsets").FirstOrDefault(),
        Spf = provider.FormData.GetValues("spf").FirstOrDefault()
    };

    // The email is now stored in the email variable

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The code above work in .NET Framework and I see another example to [MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460357/how-do-i-use-mvc-model-binding-to-get-data-from-sendgrid-inbound-parse-webhook-i) but nothing works on .net core.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I parse inbound SendGrid emails in .net core.

Given the following environment:

- Azure Function 3
- .NET Core 3.1
- StrongGrid 0.70 (via nuget) source (https://github.com/Jericho/StrongGrid)

Code:

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{

var parser = new WebhookParser();
var inboundMail = await parser.ParseInboundEmailWebhookAsync(req.Body);

inboundMail.Subject etc
...
```